# PHP - Using classes to fetch user info

Tags: php, class, fetch

Assume the connection to the database and all references to tables and cells is correct... how could I get something like this working?

```
class User  
{  

    private $_display;  
    private $_email;  

    public function __construct($username)  
    {  

        $fetch_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `registered_users` WHERE `user_name`='$username'");
        $fetch_user = mysql_fetch_array($fetch_user);

        $this->_display = $fetch_user['user_display'];  
        $this->_email = $fetch_user['user_email'];  
    }  

} 
$person1 = new User('username'); 
echo "Information: " . print_r($person1, TRUE);
```

the problem is it returns nothing. Doesn't thrown an error or anything when debugged. Is it viable method though? :S

Comment: **warning**, your code *may* vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Comment: What isn't working? What do you want to happen? Add some specificity to your question so we can give a better answer.

Comment: `$person1->_display; $person1->_email;` should print what u want

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Thanks guys - the problem is it returns nothing. Doesn't thrown an error or anything when debugged. Is it viable method though? :S

Answer (score 0):

Here is *roughly* what I would do:

```
<?php

  class User{

    private $username;
    private $data;

    public function __construct($username){
      $this->username = $username;
      if($this->valid_username()){
        $this->load();
      }
    }

    private function load(){
      // Let's pretend you have a global $db object.
      global $db;
      $this->data = $db->query('SELECT * FROM registered_users WHERE user_name=:username', array(':username'=>$this->username))->execute()->fetchAll();
    }

    public function save(){
      // Save $this->data here.
    }


    /**
     * PHP Magic Getter
     */
    public function __get($var){
      return $this->data[$var];
    }

    /**
     * PHP Magic Setter
     */
    public function __set($var, $val){
      $this->data[$var] = $val;
    }


    private function valid_username(){
      //check $this->username for validness.
    }  

    // This lets you use the object as a string.
    public function __toString(){
      return $this->data['user_name'];
    }

  }
```

How to use:

```
<?php

  $user = new User('donutdan');
  echo $user->name; //will echo 'dan'
  $user->name = 'bob';
  $user->save(); // will save 'bob' to the database
```

Comment: PHP magic getters and setters are great for these types of objects. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php